# attributeChangedCallback getting called on shallow cloneNode

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web-component

I'm trying to clone the node of a webcomponent in javascript. The component is something like this.

```js
class TestElement extends HTMLElement {
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['name']
  }
  attributeChangedCallback() {
    this.elem = document.createElement('h1');
    this.elem.innerText = this.name;
    this.appendChild(this.elem);
  }
  get name() {
    return this.getAttribute('name');
  }
  set name(value) {
    this.setAttribute('name', value);
  }
}

window.customElements.define('test-el', TestElement);
```

When I do a `node.cloneNode(false)`, I expect a single `<test-el>` node. But what I get is something like

```html
<test-el name="val">
    <h1>val</h1>
</test-el>
```

[TestElement.cloneNode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8spR.png)

This is happening because `attributeChangedCallback` is getting triggered when I clone the node. Is this the correct behaviour?

Is there any way to clone a node without triggering such DOM lifecycle callbacks?

The workaround I have now is to remove the children after cloning, but this mehtod is not very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

For Elements **with** observedAttributes, the `attributeChangedCallback` is called ***before*** the `connectedCallback` for **every** attribute observed (attributes set on the element when the Element is upgraded to a Custom Element)

```
<my-element id="ONE"></my-element>
<my-element id="TWO" attr="FOO"></my-element>
```

**logs:**

[image]

Thus `cloneNode` will trigger the `attributeChangedCallback`, when cloning `id="TWO"`

```js
customElements.define('my-element', class extends HTMLElement {
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['attr','another']
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    console.log(`connectedCallback `, this.id);
    this.innerHTML = `<h4>attr: ${this.getAttribute("attr")}</h4>`;
  }
  attributeChangedCallback(name, oldV, newV) {
    console.log(`attributeChangedCallback("${name}","${oldV}"," ${newV}")`);
  }
});
```

```html
<my-element id="ONE"></my-element>
<my-element id="TWO" attr="FOO"></my-element>
```

##### Clone element without attributes:

```
function cloneElementWithoutAttributes(element) {
  let el = document.createElement(element.tagName);
  el.append(...element.childNodes.map(node=>node.cloneNode(true)));
  return el;
}
```